Privacy guarantees in arbitrariliy-long reactive functionalities
I've been studying private function evaluation
in the case of reactive functionalities.
Please refer to section 2.5.3 of the book
Efficient Secure Two-Party Protocols by Hazay and Lindell
for a full definition.
In a PFE setting, one party, namely $A$, holds a string $x$,
and the other party, namely $B$, holds a circuit $C$,
such that $C$ takes $x$ as well as $s_t$ as input
and outputs $(y, s_{t+1})$.
In the ideal world and when both parties are honest,
the trusted third party
sends random shares of $s_{t+1}$ to the parties,
and reconstructs $s_{t+1}$ for the next round.
Let's assume every round is 'realised'
by a PFE protocol $\mathcal{P}$ with computational privacy guarantees.
Let's also assume that $A$ and $B$ are only bound
to doing $\textsf{PTIME}$ computations during each round.
My first question is:
if $\mathcal{P}$ goes on
for arbitrarily (or infinitely) many rounds,
does it lose all of its privacy guarantees,
as the hardness assumptions making it private
are no longer relevant?
The second question is:
if the answer to my first question is 'yes',
does there exist a well-known PFE protocol
with information-theoretic privacy guarantees?
I guess such a protocol reveals something about $C$ or $x$.
